# Can I use the Eclipse 4 model to build an RCP and a Plugin using the same codebase?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

The book "Eclipse 4 Plug-in Development by Example" mentions that the Eclipse 4 model provides a way to model an application.  An application has a top-level model, buy may also have additional model fragments contributed by different bundles.

Is it possible to develop an RCP and a Plugin together (same codebase) using the Application Model?  I just didn't know how you can include plugin projects into an RCP that is using the Application Model (Application.e4xmi)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have plug-ins. Plug-ins can use `fragments` to contribute to the application model:

```xml
<extension
     id="distribFragment"
     point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
  <fragment
        uri="fragment.e4xmi">
  </fragment>
</extension>
```

The `fragment.e4xmi` can import from the existing application model and can add new parts, commands, handlers....